# Вывод похожих записей WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Доброго времени суток. 
Для каждой записи указывается 7 подрубрик. Потом все они выводятся на странице.

```
                $categories = get_the_category();
                $out = '';
                if($categories){
                    foreach($categories as $category) {
                        $out .= '<a class="zap_tag" href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'">' . $category->name . '</a> ';
                    }
                    echo trim($out, ', ');
                }
```

Из всего этого облака нужно взять одну определенную подрубрику и вывести ниже похожие записи именно с такой же подрубрикой.

PHP

```
<?php
        $categories_my = get_the_category($post->ID);?>             
            <?php if ($categories_my) {                 
            foreach($categories_my as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;?>          
            <?php $args=array(                  
                    'category__in' => $category_ids, 
                    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                    'showposts'=>3, 
                    'orderby'=>'rand', 
                    'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1); 
            $my_query = new wp_query($args);
                if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
                    $my_query->the_post();
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-md-4"><a class="same_item" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?><?php echo the_excerpt(); ?></a></div>
                    <?php
                    }

                    }
            wp_reset_query();
        }
    ?>
```

На данный момент выводятся записи по нескольким подрубрикам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
foreach($categories_my as $individual_category)
    $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
```

Создавайте массив с одним элементом - идентификатором вашей категории:

```
$category_ids = array( $categories_my[0]->term_id );
```